# Delete multiple rows in mvc don't work

Tags: model-view-controller, selected

I have class connection

```
public partial class Connections
{
    public System.Guid IdConnection { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requienter code hereenter code here`red")]

    public string Sign { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public double Band { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Modulation { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public int RST { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string QLS { get; set; }



}
```

Method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteMultiple(System.Guid[] deleteInputs)

     {
           var db= new MainDbContext();
       var connections = db.Connections.ToList();
       if (deleteInputs == null)
        {

        }

       foreach (var item in deleteInputs)
    {
        Connections con = db.Connections.Find(item);
        db.Connections.Remove(con);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("EditDelete", "Connection");

    }
```

and  View:

```
@model IEnumerable<RadioSite.Connections>





          @{
    ViewBag.Title = "My connections";
       }






            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Select
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sign)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)



                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Time)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Band)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Modulation)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RST)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QLS)
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                        Actions                          
                    </th>

                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="deleteInputs" id="deleteInputs" value="@item.IdConnection" />

                        </td>


                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sign)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.Date, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.Time, "{0:HH:MM}")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Band)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Modulation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RST)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QLS)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Connection", FormMethod.Get))
                            {
                                <input type="submit" value="Edit" formaction="/Connection/Edit/@item.IdConnection" />

                            }
                            </td>

                        <td>
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteItem", "Connection", FormMethod.Post))
                            {
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete" formaction="/Connection/DeleteItem/@item.IdConnection" />



                            }



                        </td>


                    </tr>
                }


            </table>


@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteMultiple", "Connection", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Selected"/>
}
```

I selected items in grid (checked checkbox) and in method `:public ActionResult DeleteMultiple(System.Guid[] deleteInputs)`    array `deleteInputs` always is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your html.beginform pointing to "DeleteMultiple" has nothing being passed to it! You need to either restructure your view to include the inputs in your form or, since this is a delete function, make an ajax call to your controller action and send in the values of the selected check boxes.

Comment: Can you write how i can do it?